# how to get addresses of apartments and other close address with Reverse Geocoding google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-api, google-geocoding-api

I am using reverse Geocoding but its not giving me all the address for an apartment block it only gives me the address of the building how do I use reverse geocoding to give me the   potential addresses and also how do I search with a postcode using google Geocode to the same get same potential addresses too in a building

```
 function getAddressByPostal(postcode: any, country: any) {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: API.PostalUrl + postcode + '|country:' + country + '&key=' + API.API_KEY,
        }).then((res: any) => {
```

```
 function getAddressByCoord(lat: number, lng: number) {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: API.GeocodingUrl + lat + ',' + lng + '&key=' + API.API_KEY,
        }).then((res: any) => {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addresses of apartments not always available on Google Maps or the Geocoding API. When you get one, you get only one (the closest one).

You can always search (address geocoding) for an apartment address, e.g. [60 29th St. Suite #217, San Francisco](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D60%252029th%2520St.%2520Suite%2520%2523217%2520San%2520Francisco) returns a result that includes address component `subpremise: "217"`.

When addresses with such `subpremise` address components are available, they are most often found in `establishment` results (busineses). I just randomly clicked in the middle of New York City ([40.726145,-73.996875](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D40.726145%252C-73.996875)) and got one with the address "623 Broadway #2f, New York" and address component `subpremise: "2f"`.

Note that reverse geocoding is **not** intended to find *multiple addresses nearby* a location (*what is there around here?*); the functionality it provides is aimed at providing *multiple approximate descriptions* of the actual location (*where am I?*).